# Hive Divide single Integer column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have table of 3 columns in Hive and I want to divide last column based on specific value(say 200 in my case)
Hive table structure:-

```
ID ,Name ,Value 
1,"Jan",800
2,"Mar",200
3,"DEC",350
4,"APR",400
```

I want the output as

```
ID ,Name ,Value 
1,"Jan",200
1,"Jan",200
1,"Jan",200
1,"Jan",200
2,"Mar",200
3,"DEC",200
3,"DEC",150
4,"APR",200
4,"APR",200
```

I tried using lateral view explode but is is not giving me correct result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ceil(value/200)` gives the number of rows to be produced for given value. You can generate rows using `split(space(...))` + `lateral view posexplode`, then use position returned by posexplode to calculate current value.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (--demo dataset, use your table instaed of this CTE
select 1 ID,"Jan" Name,800 Value union all
select 2,"Mar",200 union all
select 3,"DEC",350 union all
select 4,"APR",400
)

select id, name, 
       --value 200 is hardcoded in many places, you can pass it as a parameter to the script
       case when (pos+1)*200 > value --remains less than 200
               then value-pos*200 
            else 200 
       end as value
from
(
select id, name, value, int(ceil(value / 200)) num_rows 
  from mytable
)s  
 --generate string of space, split it and posexplode  
 lateral view outer posexplode(split(space(num_rows-1),'')) e as pos, x
```

Result:

```
id  name    value
1   Jan      200
1   Jan      200
1   Jan      200
1   Jan      200
2   Mar      200
3   DEC      200
3   DEC      150
4   APR      200
4   APR      200
```